# SmtpClient.SendAsync() not sending emails despite not disposing of object

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code. It is in an old framework 4.7 application that does not use tasks etc but I want to try to improve the performance.

This code runs inside a parallel.Foreach

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();

smtp.SendAsync(message,null);
```

However nothing gets sent. If I change it to

```
Using(var smtp=new SmtpClient())
{
   smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Which it was originally, then everything works fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: `SendAsync` allows for asynchronous processing, but it does not magically make the SMTP client capable of sending messages in parallel over a single connection. This is explicitly documented: "After calling `SendAsync`, you must wait for the email transmission to complete before attempting to send another email message using `Send` or `SendAsync`."

Comment: But the client is created new on each loop. Would that not create multiple instances and therefore not necessitate waiting for each to complete?

Comment: In theory, yes. But if you're doing that I don't see why you wouldn't dispose the client, and moreover why you think you need `.SendAsync` in the first place, since you're already parallelizing calls in `.Send`. If you just want to use more threads, you can tell `Parallel.ForEach` to do more with `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Comment: you're not using an `await` while calling the `SendAsync` method

Comment: @HerberthGomez: you can't use `await`; `SmtpClient.SendAsync` is not task-based asynchrony. There is `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`, which is, so that might be worth experimenting with.